# Ploting igraph graph with parallel edges without superposition of edges

Tags: python, plot, igraph

I have a graph with multiple edges between vertices like below:

```
IGRAPH U-W- 5 10 --
+ attr: id (v), label (v), weight (e)
+ edges:
0 -- 1 1 2 3       2 -- 0 1 3         4 -- 1 3
1 -- 0 0 2 3 3 4   3 -- 0 1 1 2 4

edgeWeights = [10, 7, 9, 6, 9, 11, 8, 8, 5, 7]
```

I want to plot this graph showing in the edges the value of attribute weight but occurs a superposition of parallel edges. The code below is used for me to plot the graph.

```
def graphVisualization(graph, clusters):
    member = clusters.membership
    if member is not None:
        gcopy = graph.copy()
        edges = []
        edges_colors = []
        for edge in graph.es():
            if member[edge.tuple[0]] != member[edge.tuple[1]]:
                edges.append(edge)
                edges_colors.append("red")
            else:
                edges_colors.append("black")
        gcopy.delete_edges(edges)
        layout = gcopy.layout("kk")
        graph.es["color"] = edges_colors
    else:
        layout = graph.layout("ba")
        graph.es["color"] = "gray"
    visual_style = {}
    visual_style["vertex_label_dist"] = 0
    visual_style["edge_curved"] = False
    visual_style["vertex_shape"] = "circle"
    visual_style["edge_color"] = graph.es["color"]
    visual_style["vertex_size"] = 30
    visual_style["layout"] = layout
    visual_style["margin"] = 40

    graph.vs["label"] = range(0, graph.vcount())
    graph.es["label"] = graph.es.get_attribute_values("weight")

    if member is not None:
        colors = []
        for i in range(0, max(member)+1):
            colors.append('%06X' % randint(0, 0xFFFFFF))
        for vertex in graph.vs():
            vertex["color"] = str('#') + colors[member[vertex.index]]
        visual_style["vertex_color"] = graph.vs["color"]
    plot(graph, **visual_style)
```

The figure below show the graph ploted.
[image]

How I can plot the graph without superposition of egdes?

The graph with autocurve parameter.

[image]

Comment: `visual_style["autocurve"] = True` might help - it tries to make multiple edges between the same pairs of nodes visible by making them curved using a simple heuristics.

Comment: It worked Tamás but in some cases the edge weight is not close to the edge (see figure above, sorry but i dont know how to append a figure in comment). What can be done? Thank you.

Comment: You would need to patch the `get_label_position()` method in igraph's `AbstractEdgeDrawer` class to account for the curvature of the edge: https://github.com/igraph/python-igraph/blob/master/igraph/drawing/edge.py#L126 . Currently the function does not take into account the curvature of the edge so the labels are placed as if the edge was completely straight.

Comment: very nice Tamás, will be very usefull. Thanks!